# Node Script running out of memory (Loop within a loop)

Tags: javascript, performance

I have a very basic script that I've been adding on functionality to bit by bit - Hardly optimized.

It's supposed to go through X `brands` and run an API call for each one (Each has a unique endpoint) and then save the results to a CSV.

The CSV portion worked perfectly, albeit was a tad slow. (~20 seconds for 200KB file).

However, when I went to wrap all of it within a loop for the `brands` it now times out. By default it'll run 2 minutes then give me an error 
`FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory`

Which I learned to append `--max_old_space_size=4000000` to give it excess memory (It also died at 2GB). At 4GB I didn't get the error but I was getting Windows memory leak warnings so it's VERY obvious my script is having issues. I feel like it's looping during loops, but unsure.

```
var http = require("https");
var qs = require("querystring");
var csvWriter = require('csv-write-stream');
var fs = require('fs');
var moment = require('moment');
let key = '';
var brands = ['REDACTED1','REDACTED2','REDACTED3','REDACTED4','REDACTED5','REDACTED6','REDACTED7','REDACTED8']
var dataRequest = function(token){
  var date = new Date()-1; //Make it yesterday
  var formattedDate = moment(date).format('YYYYMMDD');
  var yesterdayDashes = moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
  for (var k=0;k<=brands.length;k++){

    var headers = [];
    var csvBody = [];
    var csvContent = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,";
    var options = {
      "method": "GET",
      "hostname": "REDACTED",
      "port": "443",
      "path": "REDACTED/"+brands[k]+"/"+yesterdayDashes+"?REDACTED&access_token="+token,
      "headers": {
        "authentication": "Bearer "+token,
        "content-type": "application/json",
        "cache-control": "no-cache"
      }
    }

    var req = http.request(options, function (res) {
      var chunks = [];

      res.on("data", function (chunk) {
        chunks.push(chunk);
      });

      res.on("end", function () {
        var body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
      var object = JSON.parse(body);
      var writer = csvWriter({
        headers: ["REDACTED1", "REDACTED2", "REDACTED3", "REDACTED4", "REDACTED5", "REDACTED6", "REDACTED7", "REDACTED8", "REDACTED9"]
      })
      writer.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(brands[k] +'_' +formattedDate +'_DEMOGRAPHIC.csv'))
      for (var i=0;i<object.length; i++){
        writer.write([
          object[i].field1.REDACTED1, 
          moment(object[i].optin.REDACTED2).format('YYYYMMDD HHMMSS'), 
          object[i].field2.REDACTED1, 
          object[i].field2.REDACTED2, 
          object[i].field2.REDACTED3, 
          object[i].field2.REDACTED4, 
          object[i].field2.REDACTED5, 
          object[i].field3.REDACTED6, 
          object[i].field3.REDACTED7
        ])
      }
      writer.end()
      });
    });
    req.end();
  }
}

var authToken = function(){

  var form = qs.stringify({
    grant_type: 'client_credentials',
    client_credentials: 'client_id:client_secret',
    client_id: 'cdg-trusted-client',
    client_secret: 'REDACTED'
  })
  var options = {
    "method": "POST",
    "hostname": "REDACTED3",
    "port": null,
    "path": "REDACTED3",
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      "cache-control": "no-cache"
    }
  };

  var req = http.request(options, function (res) {
    var chunks = [];

    res.on("data", function (chunk) {
      chunks.push(chunk);
    });

    res.on("end", function () {
      var body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
      var json = JSON.parse(body);
      key = json['access_token'];
    });
  });

  req.write(form);
  req.end();
  dataRequest(key);
}
authToken();
```

I removed sensitive information but all of the logic remains. This is a script I quickly threw together, but honestly going through it I don't really see any reason that it should require so much memory. I thought perhaps it was infinite looping but testing each loops within node directly I had no issues.

The flow starts getting the bearer token, once, then passing it to the function to pull data.

While I was debating putting this in CodeReview, this code isn't *technically* working at all.

**Update**
Modifying the first `for` loop now outputs an `unidentified` CSV immediately and doesn't completely anything else. However `console.log(brands[k])` is outputting the appropriate files.

**Update 2**

My version of JS debugging is putting `console.log()` everywhere, and I notice once I get below the `http.request` init, brands[k] suddenly becomes undefined. I think this might have to due with it not passing into the function?

**Update 3**

My `undefined` issue was caused by a missing semicolon, ending the for loop early. I have rectified it, but now I have a Max Stack Trace issue again.

My question context seems to now be "How do I make this `for` not run async?"

Comment: I believe Node shouldn't be the choice for such big files. I would do this operation with C and execute it with Node

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is your problem:
`for (var k=0;k=brands.length;k++){`
You have used the operator `=` which is the assignment operator and put the length of brands into the variable `k` instead of the `<` operator that check if `k` is still smaller then `brands.length`.

What happen is that the expression tested in the loop is the number 8 (the length of brands array) and it is always remains 8 so you're getting into an infinite loop.

Notice that with boolean expression any value different than `0` represent the value true while `0` represent false.

This is about the infinite loop problem, also notice there is another problem with your code with passing the token to `dataRequest` function.

The problem is your trying to pass it immediately after the req.end(); which send the request.

At this point the response still not there and the callback function of `res.on("end", ...` is still not executed.
basically you are passing undefined to the dataRequest function which cause your second error. simply move the call to `dataRequest` to happen inside the `end` callback like so:

```
res.on("end", function () {
   var body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
   var json = JSON.parse(body);
   key = json['access_token'];
   dataRequest(key);
});
```

Comment: What about it? It seems fine to me. I even tried `k<=brands.length` just in case.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I didn't think about that. I have updated my issue - Now it is immediately outputting one single, empty, 'unidentified' file, but `console.log()` shows that the brands[k] is being appropriated.

Comment: @DNorthrup you want `k < brands.length` not `<=`. `brands[brands.length]` will be undefined. The problem Ori mentions would cause your loop to make infinite requests.

Comment: No, the undefined problem relate to the way he pass the token to `dataRequest`. I updated my answer to cover that too.

Comment: @OriShalom Thanks for additional details. I made the modification you recommended but I don't quite understand how the `authToken` function is causing it. It's only ever called onInit and not again.

In addition, the `dataRequest` function worked successfully until I added this loop. Also if I move `dataRequest(key)` into the `res` I start getting a rejection due to 'no valid key'(401 basically)

Comment: You can try and return it to the way it was before, print the value of token in the `dataRquest` method and you will see for yourself that it will be undefined. The reason is Node js is a single threaded language, meaning the code doesn't wait till something that take time like HTTP call will return an answer, instead it let you define a callback to be executed later when the answer is there.
I guess there is another problem somewhere with retrieving the token.
Are you sure that the client_id and client_secret are send properly? usually with oAuth2 they will be encoded to base 64...

Comment: I have posted another answer below to show the finalized working code. Your assistance led me to finding the actual issue of the never-ending loop. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
var http = require("https");
var qs = require("querystring");
var csvWriter = require('csv-write-stream');
var fs = require('fs');
var moment = require('moment');
let key = '';
var brands = ['REDACTED1','REDACTED2','REDACTED3','REDACTED4','REDACTED5','REDACTED6','REDACTED7','REDACTED8']
var dataRequest = function(token, client){
  var date = new Date()-1; //Make it yesterday
  var formattedDate = moment(date).format('YYYYMMDD');
  var yesterdayDashes = moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    var headers = [];
    var csvBody = [];
    var csvContent = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,";
    var options = {
      "method": "GET",
      "hostname": "REDACTED",
      "port": "443",
      "path": "REDACTED/"+client+"/"+yesterdayDashes+"?REDACTED&access_token="+token,
      "headers": {
        "authentication": "Bearer "+token,
        "content-type": "application/json",
        "cache-control": "no-cache"
      }
    }; // <--- This was the culprit

    var req = http.request(options, function (res) {
      var chunks = [];

      res.on("data", function (chunk) {
        chunks.push(chunk);
      });

      res.on("end", function () {
        var body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
      var object = JSON.parse(body);
      var writer = csvWriter({
        headers: ["REDACTED1", "REDACTED2", "REDACTED3", "REDACTED4", "REDACTED5", "REDACTED6", "REDACTED7", "REDACTED8", "REDACTED9"]
      })
      writer.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(client +'_' +formattedDate +'_DEMOGRAPHIC.csv'))
      for (var i=0;i<object.length; i++){
        writer.write([
          object[i].field1.REDACTED1, 
          moment(object[i].optin.REDACTED2).format('YYYYMMDD HHMMSS'), 
          object[i].field2.REDACTED1, 
          object[i].field2.REDACTED2, 
          object[i].field2.REDACTED3, 
          object[i].field2.REDACTED4, 
          object[i].field2.REDACTED5, 
          object[i].field3.REDACTED6, 
          object[i].field3.REDACTED7
        ])
      }
      writer.end()
      });
    });
    req.end();
  }
}

var authToken = function(){

  var form = qs.stringify({
    grant_type: 'client_credentials',
    client_credentials: 'client_id:client_secret',
    client_id: 'cdg-trusted-client',
    client_secret: 'REDACTED'
  })
  var options = {
    "method": "POST",
    "hostname": "REDACTED3",
    "port": null,
    "path": "REDACTED3",
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      "cache-control": "no-cache"
    }
  };

  var req = http.request(options, function (res) {
    var chunks = [];

    res.on("data", function (chunk) {
      chunks.push(chunk);
    });

    res.on("end", function () {
      var body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
      var json = JSON.parse(body);
      key = json['access_token'];
      for (var k=0;k<=brands.length;k++){
         var client = brands[k];
         dataRequest(key, client);

    });
  });

  req.write(form);
  req.end();

}
authToken();
```

In the end I have an issue using `k = x` as stated above, once I modified it to be `k < x` I had already made multiple changes to the code causing the updates above. In addition to the `k = x` I had the semi-colon out of place above, which was breaking my `for`.

I also chose to initiate one call per `brand` instead of initiating it within the brand. The script is now working perfectly.

I have added a secondary answer to not inflate the question and to show the entire working code in the end.